# Vue.js Change placeholder in template dynamically

Tags: templates, dynamic, vue.js, vuejs2

I want change the placeholder in a template dynamically over the input of a textbox but it not work after change the value. Initial it work perfect.

**Demo**

https://jsfiddle.net/he4gx40g/

**Update:** Working example thanks @Roy J

https://jsfiddle.net/z3gbk0L2/

**Example of the component (without the textbox logic)**

```
<customValueComponent :item="config" :value="'ConfigValue1'" />
```

**Code of the customValue component**

```
customValueComponent: {
    props: {
        item: {
            type: Object,
            required: true
        },
        value: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        }
    },
    watch: {
        value: function (newVal, oldVal) { // watch it
            console.log('Prop changed: ', newVal, ' | was: ', oldVal)
            this.$options.template = '<div>{{ item.' + this.value + '}}</div>';
        }
    },
    created: function () {
        this.$options.template = '<div>{{ item.' + this.value + '}}</div>';
    },
    template: ''
}
```

**Object**

```
var config =
{
    ConfigValue1: "Titanium",
    ConfigValue2: "Gold",
    ConfigValue3: "Silver",
    ConfigValue4: "Bronze",
    ConfigValue5: "Copper",
    ...
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$options` [is read-only](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-options). This is not how you change values in a template. Vue updates values as they change. Your component definition should be

```
Vue.component('customvalue-component', {
    props: {
    item: {
      type: Object,
      required: true
    },
    value: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    }
  },
  template: '<div>{{value}}</div>'
});
```

And your binding on the component should be

```
<customvalue-component :item="config" :value="config[value1]" />
```

Comment: I want change the placeholder {{item.ConfigValue1}} or {{item.ConfigValue2}}

Comment: can you give ma example if the main object is nested, config[value1.x] or config[value1.y] ?

Comment: `config[value1].x` or `config[value1].y`. Ordinary JavaScript object indexing. `value1` is a string from the input, used as an index.